# LLDB formatter summary provider and syntactic children for template smart pointer

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I have a custom *smart pointer* template class `SP<T>`, looking like the following (simplified):

```
template<class T> class SP
{
public:
    T* operator->() const { return obj; }
    operator T*() const { return obj; }
    // other small methods (constructors, getters, setters)
private:
    T* obj;
};
```

To ease debugging in both Xcode and Android Studio, I would like to write a custom *LLDB formatter* entry for type `SP<T>` that should behave exactly the same as the underlying type `T*`.

Currently, the best I could achieve is the following simple summary provider:

```
type summary add -w alf -s "${var.obj}" -x ^SP<.*>$
```

This is already a big win, as there is now a summary displayed for objects of all types. But there are two limitations:

- If `obj==nullptr`, the summary is plain wrong because there are no check for pointer validity before dereferencing.
- For `T` types supporting syntactic children, for example arrays, I wish  the `SP<T>` to have syntactic children as well (but only if `obj!=nullptr`).

I know about summary providers functions and syntactic children classes written in Python language. What I ignore is how to *forward* a summary or syntactic children provider to another one, with an variable underlying type.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the "text format" for summaries doesn't have logic, so if you want to present a different summary for `obj == nullptr` you'll have to use a Python summary provider.

Summaries are the first choice for the value of an object that appears when evaluting summary expressions, which makes the summaries cascade automatically.  I.e. if you have:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::string some_str;
};
```

and set the summary as:

```
(lldb) type summary add -s "${var.some_str}" Foo
```

Then print a variable of that type:

```
(lldb) fr v my_foo
(Foo) my_foo = "abcd"
```

But for an array, the summary is "number of elements" and doesn't actual give access to the children.  To return structured values, you need the actual child objects not the flat summaries.

You can have an object present both the summary and the children by passing the -e option to "type summary add".  Then you could disclose the obj object in the presentation if you wanted to know more.

This will work no matter what type obj has, because, like with summaries, when the SBValue system goes to present `obj`, regardless of whether it is a top-level variable or a child (synthetic or real), it uses the same Type driven summary/synthetic child logic to decide what to show.

But I think what you really want is not "tell me what the children of this type are" but rather "replace this object with its subobject."  That would make the top level object presented for SP be `obj`.

There isn't a way to do that with the type presentation system in lldb right now.  It is focused either on flat summaries or on re-presenting the children of a value.

But that seems like a reasonable operation - though of less common use than the ones already present.  Feel free to file an ER with http://bugs.llvm.org, or take a whack at implementing it yourself (lldb is an open source project!) if you feel so motivated.